# Display few specific rows always at the top

Tags: sql-server

I want to display a few specific Rows always at top of the query results.

For example: Cities Table. Columns: City ID, City Name

I want to fetch Query result where Mumbai, Bangalore, Chennai, Hyderabad should display at the top always.

1st way:

I can insert these records first in the table so that they will get displayed always at the top.

But, this way will not work if any other city gets added after a few months that I also want to display at the top.

Comment: Add a sort by column to your table?

Comment: Show us the query you currently have so we know the correct columns names.

Comment: Add a new column Sort with data type int. And set sort value accordingly. Like
For Mumbai Sort=> 1
Bangalore Sort=> 2 ...
And fetch table data as:
select * from yourtable order by Sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`iif`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in your `order by` clause:

```
SELECT CityId, CityName
FROM Cities
ORDER BY IIF(CityName IN ('Mumbai', 'Bangalore', 'Chennai', 'Hyderabad'), 0, 1), CityName
```

You can't rely on the order in which you've entered the records to the table, because database tables are unsorted by nature, and without an `order by` clause, the order of the result set will be arbitrary.
For more information, read [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/) on my blog.

Comment: OR you can try case when:

SELECT CityId, CityName
FROM Cities
ORDER BY case when CityName in ('Mumbai', 'Bangalore') then 1 when CityName in ('Chennai', 'Hyderabad') then 2 else 3 end, CityName

Comment: @Anu Yes, that's correct. `iif` is syntactic sugar for simple `case` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Declare @t table (cityID int,cityname nvarchar(50))

insert into @t values (2,'Gujrat')
insert into @t values (4,'Surat')
insert into @t values (6,'Mumbai')
insert into @t values (3,'Bangalore')
insert into @t values (5,'Chennai')
insert into @t values (1,'Hyderabad')


select * from @t
order by case when cityname in ('Mumbai','Bangalore','Chennai','Hyderabad') then 0 else 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean way of doing this,

```
Declare @t table (cityID int,cityname nvarchar(50))
Declare @DesireOrder table (id int identity,CityID int) -- instead of cityname

insert into @DesireOrder values (6),(3),(5),(1)

insert into @t values (2,'Gujrat')
insert into @t values (4,'Surat')
insert into @t values (6,'Mumbai')
insert into @t values (3,'Bangalore')
insert into @t values (5,'Chennai')
insert into @t values (1,'Hyderabad')
insert into @t values (8,'Delhi')
insert into @t values (7,'New Delhi')

select t.* from @t t
left join DesireOrder O on t.cityid=O.cityid
order by o.id,t.cityID
```

Main idea is `@DesireOrder`, rest you can implement as per your requirement.